# What is the dominant frequency of recurring symbols spaced in time by X samples using an FFT?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, octave

I'm not an expert so I'm not sure if this has a name associated with this phenomenon or not, so I'm not sure what to search for; Perhaps this can be answered by pointing to some literature which I am unaware of.

I have a symbol which is 16 samples long, which is a sine wave. I generate input data of 256 samples long with this symbol added continuously and apply a Hann window, I get the following:

[image: Continuous sine wave, recurring sine symbols 0 spacing]

In the image, the `input` time data is shown at the top, and the `abs(fft(input))` is shown at the bottom.

Maximum FFT bin is 17, great, this is the frequency I'm looking for.

Now, I add X spaces between each symbol.

In the case below, I have added 4 samples of spacing between each symbol:

[image: Repeated sine symbols, 4 samples of spacing]

The Max FFT bin is now shifted left to bin 14; but some more higher frequency content.

I now have 8 samples between each symbol:

[image: Repeated sine symbols, 8 samples of spacing]

The Max FFT bin is now shifted left to bin 12; but even more higher frequency content.

Obviously I don't think that using the bin with the highest frequency content will give me the frequency of the sine symbol in my data as the FFT bin which has the highest frequency content shifts left as X (time spacing) increases.

I want to find a good representation of the frequency of the symbol in the input data without knowing X. Is there are better way rather than highest peak in the FFT ? I have found that a weighted average of the peaks give me a better result , but I am unsure of the genuine-ness of doing so and would prefer to use any known theory.

Comment: The bin index shifts, but not the actual frequency (since the mapping between those two depends on the FFT length). Other than that, it is very unclear (to me) what you are trying to do here. It would help if you would describe your problem, goals, requirements and constraints.

Comment: Many thanks for trying to understand - I'm scratching my head also as to how to explain it. My main issue is trying to work out the frequency of each periodic impulse, as the frequency of the impulse is identical , but the spacing is not. It's the frequency of the impulse I'm interested in.

Comment: This can probably be done with an FFT, but there may be better approaches depending on the specifics of your application